# In R, why do the p-values from anova() change when you add more predictors?

Tags: r, regression, anova, multivariate-analysis, sequential-analysis

When conducting linear regression in R, I am trying to understand how certain p-values are calculated and what they represent. So far this is my understanding:

The p-values from summary() correspond to t-tests of the marginal impact of the variables in question, *given all the other variables are already included*. This uses Type III sum of squares.

The anova() function instead uses F-tests, which are sequential testing using the Type I sum of squares.  For example, if we have the following output:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: soma
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
ht2        1  0.071  0.0710  0.1289 0.72073   
wt2        1  4.635  4.6349  8.4196 0.00504 **
ht9        1  3.779  3.7792  6.8651 0.01090 * 
Residuals 66 36.333  0.5505                   
---
```

The p-values are testing the significance of ht2 *in the presence of the intercept only*, of wt2 in the presence of *only the intercept and ht2*, and of ht9 in the presence of *the intercept, ht2, and wt2*.

Is this understanding correct? And if it is, then why do the p-values change when we add additional variables? For example:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: soma
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
ht2        1  0.0710  0.0710  0.2072 0.6504835    
wt2        1  4.6349  4.6349 13.5353 0.0004772 ***
ht9        1  3.7792  3.7792 11.0363 0.0014695 ** 
wt9        1 14.0746 14.0746 41.1018 1.878e-08 ***
Residuals 65 22.2581  0.3424                      
---
```

Adding the wt9 variable decreased the p-value for ht2. But if this is just testing the significance of ht2 in the presence of nothing but the intercept, shouldn't the p-value be identical?

Thanks in advance for any clarifications!

Comment: We have fielded many questions about this: for answers, please see the hits for [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20signif*%20change).

Comment: I checked the search you suggested, but I don't think any of the questions I saw immediately answered what I'm asking. My question is more specific to understanding how the anova() function in R calculates the F-stat and p-values.

Comment: ANOVA is regression.